# Changing the number of a sentence in a linguistics example

Tags: numbering, linguistics, gb4e

I'm using the `gb4e` package for examples in syntax. As an example:

```
\begin{exe}
\ex It is scary PRO to be near dogs.
\end{exe}
```

It shows up as sentence 1 in the PDF automatically. How do I make it, say, sentence 5 or 6 or 100?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Have you seen the `\exi` macro? According to the manual, `\exi{(5)}` should do what you want.

Answer (score 10):

The `gb4e` package has a number of ways of introducing different example numbers and depending on your actual needs you may need to use different ones.  Additionally there are two counters that control the main numbering of examples but serve slightly different purposes and are set either inside or outside the `exe` environment.  In this answer I'll try to cover all of them.

### Main example number counters: `exx` and `xnumi`

The primary example numbering is controlled by two related counters: `exx` and `xnumi`.  The `exx` counter must be set outside of the `{exe}` environment, but the `xnumi` counter must be set inside the `{exe}` environment.  As a result they cannot be used interchangeably.

So for the most basic answer to your questions there are two answers, both of which work fine, although one is conceptually more appealing in my opinion.

You can set the `exx` counter *outside* the `{exe}` environment:

```
\setcounter{exx}{<value>}
\begin{exe}
\ex An example numbered <value>
\end{exe}
```

Alternatively you can set the `xnumi` counter *inside* the `exe` environment:

```
\begin{exe}
\setcounter{xnumi}{<value>}
\ex An example numbered <value>
\end{exe}
```

Here's a full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{exx}{4}
\begin{exe}
\ex This will be example 5
\end{exe}

\begin{exe}
\setcounter{xnumi}{9}
\ex This will be example 10
\end{exe}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Extensionally these two solutions are identically, but I think the first method is conceptually more sensible for the following reasons. The typical way linguistic examples are displayed is with the main number in parentheses and if there are sub-examples these are enumerated using lower case letters. With respect to semantic markup in your source, this means that the `{exe}` environment should correspond to exactly one numbered example, with sub-examples  introduced using the `{xlist}` environment.

Thus rather doing this:

```
\begin{exe}
\ex One
\ex Two
\ex Three
\end{exe}
```

which will produce (1) (2) and (3), it's better to use three separate `{exe}` environments.

```
\begin{exe}
\ex One
\end{exe}

\begin{exe}
\ex Two
\end{exe}

etc.
```

This reflects the semantic markup better, and also makes moving examples around or splitting them up with text much simpler.

For this reason, it makes sense to control the numbering of the `{exe}` environment outside of it, and so using the `exx` counter is preferable than using the `xnumi` counter.

Furthermore, if you need to reset the numbering of examples within a document, you need to use the `exx` counter.

### When `exx` must be used

If you need to reset the example numbering within a document for any reason,  `exx` counter *must* be used.

#### Resetting example numbers on `beamer` overlays

When using the `beamer` class, overlays in Beamer create multiple pages, and so your example numbers will increment on each overlay unless you tell Beamer to reset them.  The command to reset the counters is `\resetcounteronoverlay`, and this command must use the `exx` counter in `gb4e` and not the `xlisti` counter.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\resetcounteronoverlays{exx} % using xnumi here will not work
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{A frame}
    \begin{exe}
    \ex An example\pause
    \ex An example\pause
    \ex An example
    \end{exe}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

#### Resetting examples numbers per section or chapter

If you want to have your example numbers per every chapter or section, you must make the `exx` counter depend on the `chapter` or `section` counter. But if you want to change the format of the counter itself, you must redefine `\thexnumi`.  To do this it's easiest to use the `chngcntr` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\counterwithin{exx}{section} % reset example numbers per section
\renewcommand{\thexnumi}{\thesection.\arabic{xnumi}} % change format of number
\begin{document}
\section{Section one}
\begin{exe}
\ex An example
\end{exe}
\section{Section two}
\begin{exe}
\ex Another example
\end{exe}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Other ways to change example numbers

Changing the main example number is only one of the ways to change numbers. There are some other uses which might be more appropriate for your use case.

#### Referring to a specific example from another source

If you just want to refer to a very specific number (for example a number from someone else's article) you can use the following syntax:

```
\begin{exe}
\exi{(20)} An example.
\end{exe}
```

This then doesn't require you to mess around with your main example numbering at all.

#### Repeating an example

If you want repeat an example in your text, you can use 
`\exr{<label>}` instead.  This is again preferable to resetting the number manually.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\begin{document}

\begin{exe}
\ex This is an example.\label{Ex11}
\end{exe}

\begin{exe}
\ex This is a second example.
\end{exe}

\begin{exe}
\exr{Ex11} This is an  (repeated) example.
\end{exe}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: good work, thanks for all details, hope it will be helpful for the OP.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution. Use `\setcounter{xnumi}{<value>}` inside `exe` environment.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\begin{document}

\begin{exe}
\setcounter{xnumi}{4}
\ex It is scary PRO to be near dogs.
\ex It is scary PRO to be near dogs.
\end{exe}
\begin{exe}
\setcounter{xnumi}{10}
\ex It is scary PRO to be near dogs.
\ex It is scary PRO to be near dogs.
\end{exe}
\begin{exe}
\setcounter{xnumi}{1}
\ex It is scary PRO to be near dogs.
\ex It is scary PRO to be near dogs.
\end{exe}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is actually not the preferred way to do this in `gb4e`. See my answer.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Please don't ask people to accept answers too quickly.  See [Should we wait a bit before accepting answers?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/209) for discussion. Of course the OP is free to accept any answer s/he likes, but encouraging them the accept very quickly is not really so good. In this case in particular, I don't think this answer should become the accepted one.

Comment: @AlanMunn I read your answer, may be you're right `exx` is the main counter but I can't see a difference. I am not `gbae` user and this is not objection. :-)

Comment: @touhami The two counters are in fact related but not identical. I've tried to make some sense of the mess in my answer.  For the simple case either solution will work for sure.